# ServerTime with Jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I need a js code for always getting the server time in a webpage.  This code is working but not get the time dynamically. Code gets time one time while webpage loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "GenericWCF.svc/GetSystemTime",
                    data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(bs) {
                        $("#systemTime").text(bs.d);
                  }
               });

});
```

Comment: When do you want to get the server time, if not on page load?  Do you mean you want the time to continuously update, or do you want it to get the time upon a certain event such as clicking on an element?

Comment: need continuously update Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [window.setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method to call your function which performs your ajax call.

The [window.setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method calls a function every X milliseconds repeatedly, until a call to [window.clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) is called.  Note that window.setInterval is "standard" javascript rather than jQuery.

For example:

```
window.setInterval('yourfunction()', 1000);

function yourfunction()
{
   // your ajax call here.
}
```

Will call your ajax function every 1000 milliseconds (every second).

Answer (score 0):

As @CraigTP said you have to use a timer to continuously update the time.

But why using ajax to get the time? It'll be better to just get the server time upon rendering, and then update it in the client every minute, without ajax. Just add to it a minute every minute.